# How to access other directory on docker nginx

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I made docker compose environment.
It include nginx, mysql, php-fpm, redis.
php-fpm installed laravel environment and could access root page.
But, When I make other root page on route.php and access this url, nginx looks like to not see public index.php. Do you know this cause?

**nginx error**

> nginx_1  | 2018/11/19 21:05:45 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/var/www/html/laravel_study/public/home" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /home HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    build: ./mysql
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
    - '3306:3306'
    environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_database
    - MYSQL_USER=test_user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  redis:
    build: ./redis
    image: 'redis:alpine'
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
    - web-sync:/var/www/html
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    links:
    - web
  web:
    build: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
    - web-sync:/var/www/html
    links:
    - mysql
    - redis
volumes:
  web-sync:
    external: true
```